# Windows folder shortcuts: how to have the deployed folder tree in left sidebar as well?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

In Explorer when clicking a folder shortcut I arrive directly into the folder. That's fine but I often want to have the corresponding folder tree deployed in left sidebar too. So if folder is c:\movies\action\batman\ for example, I want to see all these levels deployed in sidebar.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: How did you assign a shortcut to the folder? Try to right-click on an empty area in the navigation pane and choose "Expand to current folder" ([more info](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/65186-turn-off-navigation-pane-expand-open-folder-windows-10-a.html)).

Comment: Try to right-click an empty area in the navigation pane and check "Show all folders"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the "Expand to current folder" option. Can be found at View -> Navigation pane. With that option enabled opening the shortcut expands the folder tree in the navigation pane as you wanted.